# OpenACC - Sparse Matrix Library

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, eigen, openacc

I'm using OpenACC for sparse matrix computation in C++.
I need to use matrix operations within OpenACC regions.

Are there any sparse matrix libraries compatible with OpenACC?

I'm used to Eigen but it seems that it isn't compatible with OpenACC unless I manually modify the source code, which doesn't sound a good idea...

Comment: You'll need to explain a bit more on what you mean by "compatible" and if you're trying to use the library within an OpenACC compute region, if the library itself has been accelerated using OpenACC, or if you just want to share data between your OpenACC code and the library.  For example, if you're targeting an NVIDIA GPU, OpenACC is interoperable with cuSparse, meaning you can share data between the calls to the library and your OpenACC code.  Assuming you're using PGI, examples can be found in $PGI/linux86-64/2016/examples/CUDA-Libraries/cuSPARSE/

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Yes I want to use the library within OpenAcc region (I edited my answer to point this out). cuSPARSE seems to do the work, thank you! You can give it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're targeting an NVIDIA GPU, PGI's implementation of OpenACC is interoperable with cuSparse, meaning you can share data between the calls to the library and your OpenACC code. Assuming you're using PGI, examples can be found in $PGI/linux86-64/2016/examples/CUDA-Libraries/cuSPARSE/.  Note that cuSPARSE does not have device side routines and must be called from the host.  However, OpenACC managed device data can be passed to cuSPARSE routines via the "host_data" directive.

cuBLAS does have device routines which you can use within OpenACC compute regions.  Of course, these are not tuned for Sparse matrix operations.